# Did the term "congresscritter" originate in SF, and, if so, who first used it?

Tags: history-of, origins, terminology

The title pretty much says it all.  I thought it would be easy to find the origin by googling, but although there are many references, none of the ones I scanned included the origin.

I remember first seeing "congresscritter" decades ago, probably in *Analog*, maybe in an editorial by Stanley Schmidt.  But even if my memory is correct, did Schmidt create the word, or just use it?

I also remember that I first saw congresscritter when words like chairman, congressman and mankind were being attacked as sexist.  So that suggests early to mid 1970s for the origin.

Comment: I wonder if this question might be better off on the English Stack Exchange...?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apparently the term was coined by **Arlen Riley Wilson**, Robert Anton Wilson's wife. From [this interview with RAW](http://realitysandwich.com/5706/meeting_with_a_remarkable_man/):

> I coined the term spokesentities, because I was in a
>   restaurant in Boulder, and they gave me a card, to evaluate
>   the food, the service, this that and the other, and they asked
>   me to evaluate the waitperson. And it asks for comments.
>   So I wrote in the comments, I wrote, "Waitperson stinks
>   of human chauvinism. Change it to waitentity at once!" And I
>   signed it "animal
>   lover."
>
> And then I started using that, then, and my wife, Arlen,
>   changed it to waitcritter.. Waitcritter, **Congresscritter**;
>   clergycritter… I wouldn't want a clergy-critter getting
>   into my house. And it changes the whole abortion debate.
>   Now all they can argue about is what point after
>   the penetration of the ovum by the sperm does the resultant
>   become a critter? And when does it attain critterhood?

Comment: This is very plausible as the birth of "congresscritter".  It would have been a short journey from ARW to Stanley Schmidt. It would be nice to have the date, but that may be hoping for too much.  Now that I've thought about it more, I am pretty sure (would bet one month's income) that I saw it in Analog between 1975 and 1982.

Comment: I always assumed it originated with Walt Kelly's [*Pogo*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pogo_%28comic_strip%29) comic strip from the 1950's-70's, but according to [Wictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/congresscritter) it originated in 1979 with Jerry Pournelle, *A Step Farther Out,* Ace, page 43

Comment: Might easily have been independently invented multiple times before it became popular.

Comment: +1 for the reference "I wouldn't want a clergy-critter getting into my house."

Comment: Is there a date for this?

Comment: I echo @MarkOlson 's question: is there a date for this?

Comment: @Lexible and MarkOlson: I couldn't find one :-(

Answer (score 1):

I first ran into the term congresscritters while reading Robert A. Heinlein. He used it in several of his books going back as far as the mid 1950's.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! This answer would be improved if you could include a reference to one of Heinlein's books in which he uses the word.

Comment: It would be fascinating to have the book and the date for this!

Answer (score 0):

I can recall nationally syndicated political columnist Jack Anderson regularly using the term "Congresscritter" throughout the 1980s.

Comment: This is unlikely to be the origin as it is after both the date in the OP and the date in the accepted answer.